# Show multiple images on UIImageView with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, imageview

I have an array of imageUrl and I need to show all the images in that array on a single `UIImageView` with Fade Animation for infinite time. How to achieve this?

Currently I am using this code but it is applying animation once only:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
//animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
animation.duration = 30.0;
animation.values = imageListArray;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.repeatCount = 0;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.autoreverses = true;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[_loyaltyImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Comment: can `CAAnimationGroup`  achieve this. create a animation for every imageUrl and add all these animations to the `CAAnimationGroup`,  add `CAAnimationGroup` on the layer

Comment: @Ethan: I haven't used CAAnimationGroup. Could you share the code snippet ?

Comment: Imageview have a property that is animated images like imageView.animateImages = imageArray, you don't need to write animate function for that @nikksindia

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav: In have specified in question that I need to have fade animation which can't be achieved with 'imageView.animateImages'

Comment: change the `repeatCount` from `0` to `INT_MAX`, and `autoreverses` to `false`

Comment: agreed on repeatCount but setting autoreverse to false will cause abrupt change when the animation cycle is complete.